# Can't set different scaling to 2 monitors in Manjaro

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, xorg, kde

I have a laptop with a 4k resolution screen in which I set a scaling of 125% but this scaling affects an external monitor via HDMI that has a 1920x1080 resolution, is there a way for it not to be affected by the scaling and stays with 100% scaling?

I am working with KDE and X11.

I have tried the xrandr command with the `--scale` option but it doesn't work